# IIS Server status 500 error 0x8007000d - what's the "malformed xml element" in web.config?

Tags: http, iis, web-config, iis-8.5

I've deployed my Asp Net Core 2.0 app to an IIS server following [this guide](https://stackify.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-to-iis/) but I get **0x8007000d** status **500 error**.

According to [Microsoft's support website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942055/http-error-500-19-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage),

> This problem occurs because the ApplicationHost.config file or the
>   Web.config file contains a malformed XML element.

But I can't understand what's wrong with it... Can you help me, please?

Here's my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyFirstAngularApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Read the official guides at https://learn.microsoft.com please. Third party ones simply miss the dependencies such as .NET Core server bundle.

Comment: @LexLi thanks for having commented my question but unfortunately I didn't understand what did you mean with "Third party ones simply miss the dependencies such as .NET Core server bundle". Can you explain yourself better, please?

Comment: it is just a comment to give you hints. Use Google and you should find the answers in a few minutes.

Comment: @LexLi All right thanks, I will give another try but unfortunately all of my previous search efforts haven't been succesful. If it will have success, I will post an answer or update the question. By now, thanks for the hint!

Comment: @LexLi: That's not helpful at all. *Third party ones* ... third party *what*? I've built an ASPNet.Core 3.1 API in Visual Studio, published via VS and the **web.config** is *malformed*.

Comment: @IAbstract people like me also complained a long time ago https://blog.lextudio.com/the-horrible-story-of-publishing-net-core-web-apps-for-beginners-6121662dd8c4, and Microsoft does improve their documentation on Docs. You won't see that malformed error message (reasonable for IIS gurus, but non-sense for first time ASP.NET Core developers) if you strictly follow the Microsoft article like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to deal with this situation is to go step by step and comment out certain sections of web.config and application host.config file and check for application behavior.

So if the application still continues to throw an error after you have commented a section, then the error is elsewhere. Keep doing this and you will finally arrive at the section that is malformed.

Comment: Thank you very much! By a reading on the internet, it looks like the "elsewhere" you mentioned could be the "Startup.cs" file, `more exactly under the public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` section. Seems like it "automatically writes" web.config during deploy... Can you please confirm me this?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error when trying to deploy my Asp Net Core 3.1 app to IIS. It turns out, it had nothing to do with my web.config file containing a malformed XML element, rather it was something else.

I needed to install the Asp Net Core hosting bundle. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

This article helped me out.
https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/23/hosting-an-asp-net-core-web-application-in-iis/

Comment: This should be the first thing anyone does. Resolved my *malformed* web.config.